# setting visibility to views in RemoteViews not working

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-notifications

I'm trying to change the visibility of imagviews in the notification when one of them clicked and nothing happens even though the click trigger on the receiver has called.

My receiver code :

```
public class NotificationInteractionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (context instanceof ExoPlayerService){
        ExoPlayerService service= (ExoPlayerService) context;
        RemoteViews views=NotificationHelper.remoteViews;

        if (views==null){
            return;
        }
        if (intent.getAction().equals(NotificationHelper.NOTIFY_DELETE)){
            Log.e("NotificationReceiver","delete button clicked");
        }
        if (intent.getAction().equals(NotificationHelper.NOTIFY_NEXT)){
            Log.e("NotificationReceiver","next button clicked");
        }
        if (intent.getAction().equals(NotificationHelper.NOTIFY_PREVIOUS)){
            Log.e("NotificationReceiver","previous button clicked");
        }
        if (intent.getAction().equals(NotificationHelper.NOTIFY_PAUSE)){
            Log.e("NotificationReceiver","pause button clicked");
            views.setViewVisibility(R.id.pauseBtn_notification, View.GONE);
            views.setViewVisibility(R.id.playBtn_notification, View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (intent.getAction().equals(NotificationHelper.NOTIFY_PLAY)){
            Log.e("NotificationReceiver","play button clicked");
            views.setViewVisibility(R.id.playBtn_notification,View.GONE);
            views.setViewVisibility(R.id.pauseBtn_notification, View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: it will not work that way, clear the notification and build it again with the new view

Comment: Should I clean the RemoteViews and add a new inflated view or should I cear the notification and send a new one?

Comment: clear the notification it-self

Answer (score 0):

Missing update at end of code block. You need to enter code like this:

```
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MainWidget.class);
AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
```